# Fix issue with regex expression getting first word in string in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I am running a simple Java application and I want to grab the very first word in each string that I pass. So I did a `str.split(" ");` but I realized that my string that I have is very dynamic and it is constantly changing. So I pick up a `,` tagged on to the string which once I pass as a parameter crashes my code. So I am trying to find a particualry regex expression to just grab the very first words up until either a space, coma, period, or etc.

**Example String:**

```
WebServer, Config where AppConfig.display ends-with '/conf/workers.properties'  and Config.content.content contains 'worker.lyc_' and Config.parent.guid==WebServer.guid and exists(WebServer.container.virtualHosts.serverName contains 'www.laffatservices.gix.com')
```

My goal would to be to just grab `WebServer`.

Comment: Are you certain that there will never be a quoted string containing a space?  For example, `ends-with 'Application Support/workers.properties'`?

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to grab only the first word then here is your regex `^[A-Za-z]{2,}`.

Note that this **matches a sequence of, at least two, capital and lower letters**. And that match must be only in **the start**.

Hope that helps your case.

Comment: Your code works, but I also want to exclude spaces ```" "```. Do I just add it to the regex expression?

Comment: The regex I wrote above does not matches spaces.

Comment: So when I add spaces in front of the string I am trying to get, it doesn't find any match. However, when I remove the spaces in front, it finds a match.

Comment: What is the exact text that you want to match?

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to get it using the following ```[A-Za-z]{3}```

Comment: Actually it could mind and I am gonna tell you why. The fact that you have a regex to match your case doesn't mean that this regex is not matching anything undesirable. So you'd better be sure that `[A-Za-z]{3}` matches only your desirable results!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to `find()` first word which is NOT comma, whitespace, etc. you can use [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^ ]` and place inside all characters which you don't want. This will result in creating character class which will accept *all other characters*.

In your case you can use code like:

```
String yourText = "WebServer, Config where AppConfig.display ends-with '/conf/workers.properties'  and Config.content.content contains 'worker.lyc_' and Config.parent.guid==WebServer.guid and exists(WebServer.container.virtualHosts.serverName contains 'www.laffatservices.gix.com')";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^,\\s]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(yourText);
if (m.find()){
    String firstMatch = m.group();
    System.out.println(firstMatch);
}else{
    //handle case where there is no match found.
}
```

Output: `WebServer`

NOTE: Using `find()` will also allow you to find word even when your text starts with characters you want to skip like when `String yourText = ",,,foo,,";` result would be `foo`.

Comment: I also want to exclude space ```" "```. Do I just add it to the regex expression?

Comment: @kane_004 Can you clarify it a little bit? Add space where? Could you provide example of text which current solution fails to handle correctly and how you want it to be handled (like current result vs expected result)?

Comment: @kane_004 Notice that `\s` (written in string literal as `\\s`) represents any whitespace like tabs, which also includes regular spaces in regex.

Comment: So when I add spaces in front of the string I am trying to get, it doesn't find any match. However, when I remove the spaces in front, it finds a match.

Comment: @kane_004 "So when I add spaces in front of the string I am trying to get, it doesn't find any match" I can't reproduce this problem. Demo https://ideone.com/2iwG4H showing that result is still `WebServer` despite having spaces before it. This suggests that either problem is somewhere else (maybe you are not processing data you think you are), or that you are not using this code in similar way to what is shown in answer.